# Set limit on Clustering annotations using Mapkit

Tags: swift, xcode, mapkit, mkannotation, mkclusterannotation

I have added clustering with annotations in my project and it's working fine but having problem to set the limit.
Please check below image here, grouping is done for 6 annotations but I want to set clustering limit which should start grouping at 20 (So never see one of these with the number 19 or lower)

[image]

```
  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, clusterAnnotationForMemberAnnotations memberAnnotations: [MKAnnotation]) -> MKClusterAnnotation {
       return MKClusterAnnotation(memberAnnotations: memberAnnotations)
    }
```

Also I tried this but not working for me.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    let groupedpin = annotation as! MKClusterAnnotation

        if groupedpin.memberAnnotations.count >= 20 { //<— Not working
            let view = PlaceClusterAnnotationView.annotationView()
            view._count = groupedpin.memberAnnotations.count.description
            return view
        } 
   return MKAnnotationView()
}
```

Comment: Really good questions. Do got any good solution for this yet?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot *force* annotations to cluster, but you can *prevent* annotations from clustering. Do not give any view a `clusteringIdentifier` (meaning, set it to `nil` to prevent clustering; an empty string `""` still acts as a clustering identifier) until you want it to be able to cluster, and keep the view's `displayPriority` at `required` until you want it to be able to cluster. To try to make a view cluster, set its `displayPriority` to `0`. If you suddenly set twenty views' `displayPriority` to 0 then if they are close enough together they will probably all cluster. But you can't guarantee this.